# Mapping the 'show desktop' icon to a key (eg. F11)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to map the show desktop functionality in windows 7 to a key like F11 or F12, would prefer it if i didn't have to download a 3rd party keyboard mapping tool.  Can someone explain how?

EDIT: i know there are other shortcuts, but I'd like to remap them to a function key.  Let's say I'm quite fond of being able to do this in Mac OS X

Comment: Why would you not want to install 3rd party software? If it's lightweight or to be trusted and makes your life so much easier

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this no longer mapped to <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>?

Comment: It is, though he doesn't necessarily have to use a Windows keyboard...

Comment: Hmm. Good point.

Answer (score 7):

Do you consider Microsoft software as third party too?

[Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8be579aa-780d-4253-9e0a-e17e51db2223&DisplayLang=en)

This version is for Vista, but probably will work in 7 too.

> Ever wanted to quickly and easily
>   define your own keyboard layout for a
>   language Microsoft doesn't support? Or
>   define your own keyboard layout so you
>   can quickly and easily enter your
>   favorite symbols with a simple
>   keystroke? Well, want no more: the
>   Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator is
>   here!
>
> The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator
>   extends the international
>   functionality of Windows Vista by
>   allowing users to:
>
> - Create new keyboard layouts from scratch
> - Base a new layout on an existing one
> - Modify an existing keyboard layout (.KLC) file and build a new layout
>     from it
> - Package the resulting keyboard layouts for subsequent deployment and
>     installation.

Comment: nope, MS tools are good. i likie..

Comment: I would recommend AutoHotKey though, it's awesome in what you can program to one key. But it's third party :-)

Comment: How exactly should one use the Keyboard Layout Creator to map the "show desktop" functionality to a key?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](http://gizmodo.com/5139691/windows-7-tip-the-windows-key-is-actually-useful-now-with-tons-of-hotkey-shortcuts) and helpful comments:

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, to show desktop.
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>, to hide everything else than the active window (Similar to Aero Shake).
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, to just take a peek at your desktop.

Comment: Win + D = desktop, space indeed let's you peak (didn't know that), home doesn't do anything

Comment: Win+Home appears to hide every window except the current one. Equivalent to AERO Shake.

Comment: Aha. Thanks for clearing up :) Haven't installed Vista at work yet, so couldn't test it out.

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried it in Win 7 but Windows+M  also works in XP

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's "minimise all" (if there are any open windows), or "restore all" (if all windows are minimised)

Answer (score 1):

use auto hot key to compile a quick script, very fast and easy, write it the tutorials will give you everything you need, then compile it to an exe, and then set to run at startup.
quick
and
easy

Answer (score 1):

I think, the true answer(solution without using *any other* tool) for this question has been answered here.
https://superuser.com/a/254604/134004