# Can I change the shortcut key Windows + D?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mapping the ‘show desktop’ icon to a key (eg. F11)](https://superuser.com/questions/24011/mapping-the-show-desktop-icon-to-a-key-eg-f11)

I'd like to change the desktop shortcut from Windows+D to just the Windows key. Is it possible?

Comment: I guess it is possible somehow with AutoHotKey (http://www.autohotkey.com), but since the Windows key is a modifier key (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key) much care must be taken on how this is implemented or otherwise it will interfere with other functions like Windows+E, Windows+L, etc. So yes, it's probably possible, but since it can end up being a mess I wouldn't recommend it.